# Sending data to TELNET app with ESP8266 and arduino uno

Tags: esp8266, arduino-uno

I started to test the ESP8266 module, i wrote in the serial port this commands: AT, AT+RST, AT+CWMODE=1(station mode), AT+CWLAP, AT+CWJAP="My network name","password", AT+CIPMUX=1, AT+CIPSERVER=1,80, AT+CIPSEND=0,"numer of char of my string",  "MyMessage", AT+CIPCLOSE=0 and it work, its sends the message to my phone.
Now I try to do some function that sends automatically those commands, but when i get to the sending message part it gives me an error.
I post my code below:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial ESPserial(9, 10); // RX | TX

void setup()

{

Serial.begin(9600); // communication with the host computer

// Start the software serial for communication with the ESP8266
ESPserial.begin(9600);
delay(1000);
Serial.println("");
Serial.println("Remember to to set Both NL & CR in the serial monitor.");
Serial.println("Ready");
Serial.println("");
trimiteDate("AT+IPR=9600",1000);
trimiteDate("AT",1000);
trimiteDate("AT+RST",1000);
trimiteDate("AT+CWMODE=1",1000);
trimiteDate("AT+CWLAP",1000);
trimiteDate("AT+CWJAP=\"DIGI_d61430\",\"ddcc29eb\"",1000);
trimiteDate("AT+CIFSR",1000);

trimiteDate("AT+CIPMUX=1",1000);
trimiteDate("AT+CIPSERVER=1,80",1000);
scrie("Sir de caractere",1000);


}

void loop()

{
// listen for communication from the ESP8266 and then write it to the serial monitor
if ( ESPserial.available() ) { Serial.write( ESPserial.read() ); }
// listen for user input and send it to the ESP8266
if ( Serial.available() ) { ESPserial.write( Serial.read() ); }
}


void trimiteDate(String comanda, const int timp ){
    ESPserial.println(comanda);

while ( ESPserial.available() ) { Serial.write( ESPserial.read() ); } 
while ( Serial.available() ) { ESPserial.write( Serial.read() );}
  delay(timp);
  } 


 void scrie(String sir, const int timp){
      int lungimeSir = sir.length();
      String startTransmisie = "AT+CIPSEND=1,";
      String stopTransmisie = "AT+CIPCLOSE=0";
      String sirDate = startTransmisie + lungimeSir;
      trimiteDate(sirDate,1000);

      ESPserial.println(sir);

      trimiteDate(stopTransmisie,1000);
      delay(timp);
  
  
  }
```

Comment: you must wait for the prompt `>` before sending data.

Comment: So i should put a delay of about 3-4 seconds right before ESPserial.println(sir) in the *scrie* function?